# Is the set of elements of sequence closed?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

> Let $(x_n)_n$ be a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.
>   Let $A$ be the following set: (suppose $A$ is infinite)
>
> $$ A= \{x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{n} \} $$
>
> Prove or give a counterexample:
>   $A$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Here's what I tried:

$$ A = \bigcup_{x \in A} \{x\}$$
$$ A^c = \bigcap_{x \in A} \left( ]-\infty,x[\ \cup\ ]x,.\infty[ \right)$$

This is the union of open intervals between the elements in $A$, so $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ is open, thus $A$ is closed.

Intuitively I say that this is the union of open intervals, but this is not rigurous. Any help?

EDIT: Is this *always* false? Is this true if $A$ is *not* infinite?

Comment: If $A$ is not finite then $A^c$ is here an infinite countable *intersection* of open sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general $A$ defined as in your question is not closed.

Example: if $x_n=\frac1{n}$ then $(x_n)_n$ is a convergent sequence in $\mathbb R$.

However the set $A=\{\frac1{n}\mid n=1,2,\dots\}\subset\mathbb R$ is not closed.

Element $0$ is a limitpoint of $A$ but does not belong to $A$.

---

**Edit** (on edit of question):

If again $x_n=\frac1{n}$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ and next to that $x_0=0$ then $A=\{0\}\cup\{\frac1{n}\mid n=1,2,\dots\}$ hence is closed.

Comment: Regarding the follow-up questions from the edit: If $A$ is finite, it is indeed closed (as the finite union of closed one-point sets). It is false if $A$ doesn't contain $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ (that is usually).

Comment: Can you prove that if A contains the limit, it is closed?

Comment: Yes. Since the sequence is convergent only the limit of the sequence can be a [limitpoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) of $A$. So if $A$ contains the limit then it contains all of its limitpoints hence is closed.